# Zenity alternative for Android

Tags: android, notification

Is there any [Zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) alternative available for Android?

I am trying to do something like this using a Bash script in my Android device:

1. Show a pop-up message
2. Play a notification tone
3. Show a pop-up window with text (or number) input box;
4. Add item to notification panel;
5. Show toaster message?

Is it possible to do this without using any external tool (or with only lightweight external tool)? If not then please name some command-line tools for this purpose.

Expected usage scenario, from command line:

```
$ ANWSER=$(android_show_message --buttons OK,Cancel "Do you really want ...?" )
 (android_show_message script brings up a tiny apk app using `am start`)
 (android_show_message communicates with the app to configure what it want to do)
 (android_show_message waits until the app tells it to exit)
 user presses "OK", android_show_message exits successfully, printing "OK";
$ if [ "$ANSWER" == "OK" ]; then android_show_message --toast "Operation completed"; fi
 (a toast message is shown)
```

Comment: It can be implemented as a pair of "apk" application that shows dialog and a script that manages connection to this apk (using sockets or sd card).

Answer (score 1):

Installing a command line tool will need a terminal app to be installed on your device. Instead you can use following third-party tools

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) can do these things for you.

Just a little heads-up. It is a paid app and a trial version is available. Please test it before you buy. It needs little advanced understanding.

There is also [Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher&hl=en)

Simple, free but has limited workings
Let us know which one you choose.

Comment: How do I call from bash to Tasker/Trigger and read user's input back in bash?

Comment: Also someting simple expected, but a complex thing that can be also misused as just a message/inputbox shower from remote.

Comment: There is no exact alternative. but both apps can automate the tasks you needed. what you are trying to do exactly by taking input back to terminal?

Comment: To have interactive scripts that work on Linux also work on Android.

Comment: It will not be possible with android. Android carries XML framework to build  GUI. Zenity uses GTK framework which is made up of many languages like C, perl python, cpp and lots but does not consist any XML elements. you can always go for command line apps using c or python

Comment: I need not a port of Zenity, but an analogue. I do something like `show_message --buttons OK:Cancel "Hello, world"` in the command line, the apk application knows it pops up a window with the respective controls, user clicks on a button, the `show_message` prints the approriate text (i.e. `Cancel`) and exits.

Comment: Is is necessary to have it on command line?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of Zenity is to be able to show simple GUI messages from command line in easy way. For Android I expect it to be able to show "toaster" messages, add things to notification bar and finally show messages boxes with input box, list chooser and buttons. The invocation script should exit back to command line when user interacts with those elements somehow.

Comment: there are python libraries available for zenity..so u can use those with python script - [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity#Cross-platform_script_example) is an example. For python support use [Qpython](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus&hl=en) or similar app. This should provide you complete solution.

Comment: For this there should be Python + something toolkit to support Zenity already on Android. This leads to heavy-weight solution. Also the way of communication between "command line world" and "Android GUI world" is not covered.

Comment: Qpython supports python on android. Scripting will be in python using provided python library. It will not be shell scripting. Or execute python program using shellscript

Comment: I think u need specific command line alternative. But according to my knowlege it does not exist yet. I tried to provide alternative solutions but your needs cannot be satisfied. Long chats are forbidden hence terminating  conversation here and soon the answer will be deleted by me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with [termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) and the [termux-api](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:API) ([**apk**](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux.api/)) extension which exposes among other commands the [termux-dialog](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-dialog):

```
confirm - Show confirmation dialog
    [-i hint] text hint (optional)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

checkbox - Select multiple values using checkboxes
    [-v ",,,"] comma delim values to use (required)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

counter - Pick a number in specified range
    [-r min,max,start] comma delim of (3) numbers to use (optional)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

date - Pick a date
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)
    [-d "dd-MM-yyyy k:m:s"] SimpleDateFormat Pattern for date widget output (optional)

radio - Pick a single value from radio buttons
    [-v ",,,"] comma delim values to use (required)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

sheet - Pick a value from sliding bottom sheet
    [-v ",,,"] comma delim values to use (required)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

spinner - Pick a single value from a dropdown spinner
    [-v ",,,"] comma delim values to use (required)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

speech - Obtain speech using device microphone
    [-i hint] text hint (optional)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)

text - Input text (default if no widget specified)
    [-i hint] text hint (optional)
    [-m] multiple lines instead of single (optional)*
    [-n] enter input as numbers (optional)*
    [-p] enter input as password (optional)
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)
       * cannot use [-m] with [-n]

time - Pick a time value
    [-t title] set title of dialog (optional)
```

An example of a text input (`text` can be omitted as it's the default widget type):

```
termux-dialog text -t "Please enter a name"
```

The result is returned as json so you'd probably want to use something like [**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse it.

```
name=$(termux-dialog text -t "Please enter a name" | jq '.text')

echo "$name"
```

If you put your scripts into the `~/.shortcuts` folder then you can run them with a single tap via the [Termux Widgets](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux.widget/) add-on.